# Create a DataFrame birds from this dictionary data which has the index labels

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Python dictionary data and Python list labels:**

```
data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'],
        'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, np.nan, 6, 3, 5.5, np.nan, 8, 4],
        'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2],
        'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Create a DataFrame birds from this dictionary data which has the index labels using Pandas

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary is already ordered into the correct ordering for the labels

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'],
    'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, np.nan, 6, 3, 5.5, np.nan, 8, 4],
    'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2],
    'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

data['labels'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['birds', 'age', 'visits', 'priority', 'labels'])
df.set_index('labels')
```

Comment: im getting this error
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-54d059f8c43c> in <module>()
      2 
      3 data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'],
----> 4     'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, np.nan, 6, 3, 5.5, np.nan, 8, 4],
      5     'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2],
      6     'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: Add `import numpy as np` under `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
data = {
    'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'],
    'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, np.nan, 6, 3, 5.5, np.nan, 8, 4],
    'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2],
    'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no'],
    'labels' : labels
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.set_index('labels')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce some code like:

DataFrame provides us a flexibilty to provide some values like data,columns,index and the list goes on.

If we are dealing with Dictionary, then by default dictionaries keys are treated as column and values will be as rows.

In following Code I have used name attribute through DataFrame object

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=Labels) # Custom indexes
df.index.name='labels'             # After Running df.index.name you will get index as none, by this approach you can set any name to the column
```

I hope this will be help full for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even I encountered the same exact issue few days back and we have a very beautiful library to handle dataframes and is better than pandas.

Search for turicreate in python, it is very very similar to the pandas but has a lot more to offer than pandas.

You can define the Sframes in Turi[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgO2r.png), somewhat similar to the pandas dataframe. After that you just have to run:

dataframe_name.show()

.show() visualizes any data structure in Turi Create.

You can visit the mentioned notebook for a better understanding: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DIFmRjGYx0UOiZtvMi4lOZmaBMnu_VlD

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'],
        'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, np.nan, 6, 3, 5.5, np.nan, 8, 4],
        'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2],
        'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

df=DataFrame(data,index=labels)
print(df)
```